# Disable iPhone "save image" popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I am trying to disable the "save image" dialoge from showing on the iPhone/any iOS device. When a user is in Safari they can hold their finger down on an image and they can save that image directly to their phone. Is their a way to diable this menu with javascript, jquery, or css?

I have looked around at other posts and there does not seem to be that much on this topic. I found one post but the answer did not seem to work.

I saw one method of using an invisible div but I prefer not to do this if it can be done with jQuery or javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `-webkit-user-select:none;` and/or `-webkit-touch-callout:none;`?

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for: [-webkit-touch-callout](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-touch-callout)

Answer (score 2):

-webkit-touch-callout

This might be helpful: http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit