# How can you prevent mobile browsers from prompting to copy image after holding touch

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, mobile, safari

I have two arrow images that appear on the left and right of a menu when the screen size is small (for mobile browsers). You can touch and hold to scroll the menu bar left or right.

I've so far tested the menu on my iPhone using Chrome and when you hold down the arrows to scroll the menu, it will prompt you and ask if you want to copy the image (as well as some other options). I want to block this from happening if possible because it is obviously an annoying experience.

Does anyone know how this might be done?

Comment: set as background images?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8973715/125629